# EF5, code first exception ONLY on first database access: "FK_x...x' is not a constraint. Could not drop constraint"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first

This has been driving me crazy for days.  I am using vs2012, EF5 code first, sql server 2012.  This is on my development machine and ***I get the below exception when, and ONLY when, I hit the database the very first time***.  If, before I run my tests, I init the database, it throws the below exception, **but not thereafter**. If I run my tests, the first test fails because of this exception, **but all my other tests pass**.  If I catch the exception and ignore it, **all my tests pass without error**.  What is frustrating, is I've defined constraints, between those two tables, but don't know where 'Users_Id' is defined.  I've also tried manually deleting the tables and running the vs2012 generated sql from my DbContext to recreate the table fresh, but nothing works.  Any help would be much appreciated.

**Here is the exception**

*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'FK_dbo.UserProfiles_dbo.Users_Id' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.*

**Here are my pocos**

**User**

```
public class User : Entity<User>, IUser
   {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      // Nav property to UserProfile.
      public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
      public Guid SiteId { get; set; }
      public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
   }
```

**UserProfile**

```
public class UserProfile : Entity<UserProfile>, IUserProfile
   {
      // Points to User.Id
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      // Nav property back to user.
      public virtual User User { get; set; }
   }
```

**Here's my code first definition of the two tables** (other code left out for brevity):

**EDIT: The relationship between the two tables is Id User.Id => UserProfile.Id**

**User**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
         modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(p => p.Site).WithMany(p => p.Users).HasForeignKey(p => p.SiteId);
         modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                   .HasRequired(p => p.UserProfile)
                   .WithRequiredPrincipal(p => p.User)
                   .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

**UserProfile**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
         modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().HasRequired(p => p.User);
```

Comment: It may have to do with the redundant `modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().HasRequired(p => p.User);` (you already define this in `WithRequiredPrincipal`).

Comment: @GertArnold - that wasn't it; if I comment out that out, still get the same exception :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This fixed it**

**In my DbContext**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
         Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, ContextConfiguration>());

         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      }
```

**My Migration Configuration**

```
public class ContextConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context>
   {
      public ContextConfiguration()
      {
         this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
         this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
      }
   }
```

**In My Tests**

```
[TestInitialize]
      public override void TestInitialize()
      {
         // Force model updates.
         using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Instance.Create<UnitOfWorkCore>(DefaultConnectionString))
         {
            uow.Database.Initialize(force: false);
         }

         // begin transaction
         this.transactionScope = new TransactionScope();

         this.unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Instance.Create<UnitOfWorkCore>(DefaultConnectionString);
      }
```

**I changed things to this and not no problems**
**I changed things to this and not no problems**
**I changed things to this and not no problems**

**In My Tests**

```
[TestInitialize]
      public override void TestInitialize()
      {
         // Force model updates.

         // I CHANGED TO THIS:
         Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>());

         using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Instance.Create<UnitOfWorkCore>(DefaultConnectionString))
         {
            uow.Database.Initialize(force: false);
         }

         // begin transaction
         this.transactionScope = new TransactionScope();

         this.unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Instance.Create<UnitOfWorkCore>(DefaultConnectionString);
      }
```